# Assigning 4 different players to a station by round with no repeats

Tags: r, dplyr, combinations, permutation

I am building an r-script that uses all the possible combinations of 4 different variables: Rounds, Stations, and Players (Male and Female). Below is my dput version of the dataset:

```
structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("round1", "round2", "round3"
), class = "factor"), x.x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("station1", "station2", 
"station3"), class = "factor"), x.y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("male1", 
"male2", "male3", "male4", "male5", "male6"), class = "factor"), 
y = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("female1", "female2", "female3", 
"female4", "female5", "female6"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("x", 
"x.x", "x.y", "y"), row.names = c(55L, 109L, 163L, 217L, 271L, 
10L, 118L, 172L, 226L, 280L, 19L, 73L, 181L, 235L, 289L, 28L, 
82L, 136L, 244L, 298L, 37L, 91L, 145L, 199L, 307L, 46L, 100L, 
154L, 208L, 262L, 58L, 112L, 166L, 220L, 274L, 13L, 121L, 175L, 
229L, 283L, 22L, 76L, 184L, 238L, 292L, 31L, 85L, 139L, 247L, 
301L, 40L, 94L, 148L, 202L, 310L, 49L, 103L, 157L, 211L, 265L, 
61L, 115L, 169L, 223L, 277L, 16L, 124L, 178L, 232L, 286L, 25L, 
79L, 187L, 241L, 295L, 34L, 88L, 142L, 250L, 304L, 43L, 97L, 
151L, 205L, 313L, 52L, 106L, 160L, 214L, 268L, 56L, 110L, 164L, 
218L, 272L, 11L, 119L, 173L, 227L, 281L, 20L, 74L, 182L, 236L, 
290L, 29L, 83L, 137L, 245L, 299L, 38L, 92L, 146L, 200L, 308L, 
47L, 101L, 155L, 209L, 263L, 59L, 113L, 167L, 221L, 275L, 14L, 
122L, 176L, 230L, 284L, 23L, 77L, 185L, 239L, 293L, 32L, 86L, 
140L, 248L, 302L, 41L, 95L, 149L, 203L, 311L, 50L, 104L, 158L, 
212L, 266L, 62L, 116L, 170L, 224L, 278L, 17L, 125L, 179L, 233L, 
287L, 26L, 80L, 188L, 242L, 296L, 35L, 89L, 143L, 251L, 305L, 
44L, 98L, 152L, 206L, 314L, 53L, 107L, 161L, 215L, 269L, 57L, 
111L, 165L, 219L, 273L, 12L, 120L, 174L, 228L, 282L, 21L, 75L, 
183L, 237L, 291L, 30L, 84L, 138L, 246L, 300L, 39L, 93L, 147L, 
201L, 309L, 48L, 102L, 156L, 210L, 264L, 60L, 114L, 168L, 222L, 
276L, 15L, 123L, 177L, 231L, 285L, 24L, 78L, 186L, 240L, 294L, 
33L, 87L, 141L, 249L, 303L, 42L, 96L, 150L, 204L, 312L, 51L, 
105L, 159L, 213L, 267L, 63L, 117L, 171L, 225L, 279L, 18L, 126L, 
180L, 234L, 288L, 27L, 81L, 189L, 243L, 297L, 36L, 90L, 144L, 
252L, 306L, 45L, 99L, 153L, 207L, 315L, 54L, 108L, 162L, 216L, 
270L), class = "data.frame")`
```

Below are the first 10 rows:

```
     Round  Station Partner1 Partner2
55  round1 station1    male1  female2
109 round1 station1    male1  female3
163 round1 station1    male1  female4
217 round1 station1    male1  female5
271 round1 station1    male1  female6
10  round1 station1    male2  female1
118 round1 station1    male2  female3
172 round1 station1    male2  female4
226 round1 station1    male2  female5
280 round1 station1    male2  female6
```

In this dataset there are the following:

3 Rounds, 3 Stations, 6 Male, 6 Female

How do I do the following:

1) No person should be in the same station twice

2) No person should be in the same round twice

3) No person should be partnered with the same person twice

4) Each station requires 2 male and 2 female

5) Ideally, each person should be with people in a round that have not been with them in previous rounds.

6) A player with the same number at the end (male1, female1) should never be partnered

So the final output should look something like this for one of the rounds:

```
     Round  Station Partner1 Partner2
55  round1 station1    male1  female5
109 round1 station1    male3  female4
163 round1 station2    male2  female3
217 round1 station2    male4  female1
271 round1 station3    male5  female6
10  round1 station3    male6  female2
```

For round2, all 3 stations should still be present but the male and female partners need to change and should follow the rules described above.

*Also, let me know if this is mathematically impossible without adding additional stations.*

Any help would be great!

Comment: Just add 1 to each male's station for the next round, and subtract 1 to each female's station for the next round (mod 3). If you're ever in a situation where male number = female number, have the two females at the same station switch.

Comment: Thanks for the input Gregor! Would this logic work by station by round as well?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It will generate the next two rounds based on a valid starting round like you have.

Comment: Also, I would recommend using *italics* for empasis RATHER THAN ALL CAPS, WHICH FEELS VERY SHOUTY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. I ignore (5) because it does not seem to be a strict requirement (and I don't think it is possible as a strict rule).

This function takes a valid first round as input, and outputs a good configuration for the second round (and the third, if applied again).

I modified your data to have numbers which are much easier to manipulate than strings. Strictly speaking, only the `Partner` columns (renamed to `Male` and `Female`) need to be numbers for the function to work.

```
# data
r1 = read.table(text = "     Round  Station Partner1 Partner2
55  round1 station1    male1  female5
109 round1 station1    male3  female4
163 round1 station2    male2  female3
217 round1 station2    male4  female1
271 round1 station3    male5  female6
10  round1 station3    male6  female2", header = T)

# numericize
r1$Round = as.numeric(substr(r1$Round, 6, 6))
r1$Station = as.numeric(substr(r1$Station, start = 8, stop = 8))
r1$Male = as.numeric(substr(r1$Partner1, 5, 5))
r1$Female = as.numeric(substr(r1$Partner2, 7, 7))
r1[c("Partner1", "Partner2")] = list(NULL)

# function
next_round = function(r) {
  r$Male = r$Male[c(3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2)]
  r$Female = r$Female[c(5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4)]
  problems = which(r$Male == r$Female)
  # switch male problems
  switch_with = ifelse(problems %% 2 == 0, problems - 1, problems + 1)
  r$Male[c(rbind(switch_with, problems))] = r$Male[c(rbind(problems, switch_with))]
  # increment round
  r$Round = r$Round + 1
  return(r)
}

# demonstration
r1
#     Round Station Male Female
# 55      1       1    1      5
# 109     1       1    3      4
# 163     1       2    4      3
# 217     1       2    2      1
# 271     1       3    5      6
# 10      1       3    6      2
(r2 = next_round(r1))
#     Round Station Male Female
# 55      2       1    2      6
# 109     2       1    4      2
# 163     2       2    6      5
# 217     2       2    5      4
# 271     2       3    1      3
# 10      2       3    3      1
(r3 = next_round(r2))
#     Round Station Male Female
# 55      3       1    6      3
# 109     3       1    5      1
# 163     3       2    1      6
# 217     3       2    3      2
# 271     3       3    4      5
# 10      3       3    2      4
```

Essentially what this does is that the males and females stay with the same-sex partners from their starting stations. Males move down one station number each round, females move up one station number each round, and if there is ever a Male = Female collision the males at that station switch to correct it. I was inspired by square dancing, where males and females moving in different directions to rotate partners is common.

Comment: I'll stop with the caps :)

Comment: I like the comparison also to Square Dancing because that's pretty much what this is